# htaccess redirecting all url to default profile page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i am having problem in my .htaccess. what happened was that changed htaccess by adding this :-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

to it but after that it also redirects all url after the domain to some default like profile page for eg : if i enter domain.com/edit.php it shows profile.php page but edit.php does not exist rather it should show 404 page but that does not happen.

Here is my .htaccess , is it right and is it affecting my SEO also.

```
Options +Indexes
# or #
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879029/dont-understand-rewritecond-request-filename-f-and-d

Comment: but it says it is used to redirect to index.php but mine is redirecting it to profile.php why ?

Comment: because the next string after these two is referring to profile.php

Comment: so what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then proceed to the rewrite rule immediately below these strings

In your case the rule is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
```

So if you want anything specific happen in case of not found page, add some other rule (redirect to 404 page, etc) just under the string with `-d` and `-f` flags.

Or remove these strings and add a link to your 404 error document like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errordoc.php
```

or link index.php as error document

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```